# SQL query: Grab data from a multiple columns conditionally

Tags: sql, database

I just started working with SQL.  The data is stored as in three tables.  An example is given below...

**TABLE1**

column: product family

**TABLE2**

column: location

**TABLE3**  columns of intrest:

building plant

product type

forcast2012

forcast2013

forcast2014

forcast2015

If...
any text value stored in "location" matches a given text value in "building plant" & If any text value stored in "product family" matches a given text value in "product type"

then...
grab the contents of the four columns "forcast2012, forcast2013, forcast2014, forcast2015" in the corresponding rows and build a new table consisting of them and their matched "location" and "product family" values.

Comment: What you have so far?

Comment: Here is what I have so far:  It is courtesy of @Bill Gregg.

Comment: select facility.location, ProductFamily.productfamily, [2012 Full Units w/C], [2013 Full Units w/C],  [2014 Full Units w/C],  [2015 Full Units w/C], [2016 Full Units w/C], [2017 Full Units w/C], [2018 Full Units w/C]
from strap
inner join strap on ProductFamily.productfamily = strap.[prod series]
inner join facility on strap.[building plant] = facility.location

Comment: I have just changed the table and column names to reflect their actual values.  however I'm getting a syntax error (missing operator)

Comment: your first join is "strap inner join strap".  Should be "strap inner join ProductFamily"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select table2.location, table1.productfamily, forcast2012, forcast2013, forcast2014, forcast2015
from table1 
inner join table3 on table1.productfamily = table3.producttype
inner join table2 on table3.[building plant] = table2.location
```